# Why the lines that are before a sleep instruction are not executed?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, sleep

I made a Window class and I'm working with some buttons.
I have a problem with one of them that first it executes a sleep line, that it is at the end of my code, instead of execute the lines before

The program took a 1 second before to set the button's and label's texts but the function sleep() is after these lines.

```py
def BntStart(self):
    btnText = "Detener"
    self.btn.setText(btnText)
    self.label.setText("Gracias por presionarme")
    #If I add this line the 3 lines above aren't executed
    time.sleep(1)
```

Someone knows why is this happening?

Comment: Changes aren't rendered immediately, they're rendered when the function returns to the main event loop.

Comment: before `sleep()` use `root.update()` to force `tkinter` to redraw window immediately.

Comment: The lines _are_ executed, the display just hasn't been updated yet. The call to `sleep()` prevents the `mainloop()` from running. In a `tkinter` application so it doesn't happen. You should instead use the univeral widget [`after()`](http://web.archive.org/web/20190121045017id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) method, which wouldn't do that. You don't need to call `root.update()`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specify using multiple threads, your program will be running on a single thread. Presumably there is a call somewhere else in your thread where you ask the program to update the graphics. However, once the program is told to sleep, thread execution will not continue until the sleep is complete, so the graphics will not update until after the sleep has been done.

One solution to this is to us [multiple thread](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/) and a [MVC (Model View Controller)](https://realpython.com/the-model-view-controller-mvc-paradigm-summarized-with-legos/) paradigm, where the view and the controller are running on separate threads. This allows the program to keep processing how it wants to control the graphics, while also rendering them.

### Edit

As is this is a tkinter issue, this [other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250624/stop-tkinter-window-from-freezing-while-program-is-sleeping) is near identical

Comment: Generally speaking, `tkinter` doesn't support multi-threading, so that's not a solution in this case.