# The program won't wait between changing text in Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter, label, config

I want to display a piece of text in a label, but it'll skip to the second change.

```
def retrieveThickness():
     try:              
         t = float(width_input.get())
         stsDesc2.config(text = "Now give me the THICKNESS of the specimen(mm)")
         OK_Button1.config(command = retrieveThickness)
         Crs_Sect = w * t
         time.sleep(0.1)
         stsDesc2.config(text = "The CROSS SECTION is " + str(Crs_Sect) + "mm squared")
         time.sleep(5)
         stsDesc2.config(text = "How many values do you want to calculate the stress for?")
     except ValueError:
         response = "Field can't be empty, have any letters or symbols other than ."
         errorLabel = tkinter.Label(stsWindow,
                                    text = response,
                                    font = ("Arial",10, "bold"))
         errorLabel.grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky = "N", padx = 20, pady = 20)
```

When it calculates crs_sect, it doesn't display "The CROSS SECTION is " + str(Crs_Sect) + "mm squared" onto the label. It immediately goes to time.sleep(5) and then changes the label to "How many values do you want to calculate the stress for?".

Comment: There must be dozens of questions like this on this site. When you do `time.sleep(5)`, you're preventing tkinter from refreshing the window.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [stop tkinter window from freezing while program is sleeping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250624/stop-tkinter-window-from-freezing-while-program-is-sleeping)